# How to get x where y is maximum?

Tags: r

**without a loop.**

This below, gives me the maximum difference between 2 distributions (value of y).

```
x.e <- ecdf(x)
y.e <- ecdf(y)
mx <- max(x,y)    
max(abs(x.e(seq(0,mx,mx/1000)) - y.e(seq(0,mx,mx/1000))))
```

How to get WHERE this maximum is reached (value of x).

Comment: Generally speaking, you can get the indices of maxima using `which(x == max(x))` for all indices or `which.max(x)` to get only the first max index.

Answer (score 0):

@docendo discimus , @danas.zuokas , thx for help. :)

So it goes like this:

```
x.e <- ecdf(x)
y.e <- ecdf(y)
mx <- max(x,y)

  steps <- seq(0,mx,mx/1000)
  dif <- abs(x.e(steps) - y.e(steps))

  y.max <- max(dif)
  x.max <- steps[which.max(dif)]
```